# Many to many helper table not being created in unit tests

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a Flask app that uses SQLAlchemy and I'm having trouble getting my many to many relations working with my unit tests.

In my `setUp` method I create my app and initialise my database like this:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

def setUp(self):
    self.app = create_app(env='test')
    self.app.logger.disabled = True
    db.init_app(self.app)
    with self.app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

And in my models.py I define my many-to-many like this:

```
contact_buying_categories = db.Table('contact_buying_category',
    db.Column('contact_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contact.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('buying_categories.id'))
)

class Contact(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'contact'
    __bind_key__ = 'db1'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    buying_categories = db.relationship('BuyingCategory',
                                        secondary=contact_buying_categories)


      ...

class BuyingCategory(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'buying_categories'
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

When I run my unit tests, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: contact_buying_category 
u'SELECT buying_categories.id AS buying_categories_id, buying_categories.name AS 
buying_categories_name \nFROM buying_categories, contact_buying_category \nWHERE ? = 
contact_buying_category.contact_id AND buying_categories.id = 
contact_buying_category.category_id' (1,)
```

If I drop into IPDB after the `create_all()` call in `setUp` and do a `db.metadata.tables`, it has the table definition:

```
'contact_buying_category': Table('contact_buying_category', MetaData(bind=None), 
Column('contact_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('contact.id'), table=
<contact_buying_category>), Column('category_id', Integer(), 
ForeignKey('buying_categories.id'), table=<contact_buying_category>), schema=None),
```

I'm confused, why can't the app find the `contact_buying_category` table?  How can I check if it's actually been created?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set a bind_key on my many to many relation for Flask-SQLAlchemy to take any notice of it in the call to `db.create_all()`.

```
contact_buying_categories = db.Table('contact_buying_category',
    db.Column('contact_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contact.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('buying_categories.id')),
    info={'bind_key': 'wdl'}
)
```